# How to control fields displayed in Show All Records page of Related List?

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, related-list, search-layout

Environment: Salesforce Classic & Service Cloud Console.

For Some reasons, I'm developing a related list of Cases for an object with Visualforce, to replace the original one. I added a link into that VFpage just like the original "show all records" link.
For example, `https://ap6.salesforce.com/007?id=0012800000siJrz&rlid=RelatedActivityList&closed=0`

Here is the question.
If I use the original related list of Cases, I can see the fields displayed can be controlled by page layout settings.
But, because I replaced it with my developed one, I don't know how to set up which fields to show up in the "all records" page.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use field set to control the fields from the object level to be shown on the Visual force page. A field set is a grouping of fields, you can use the field set in visual force page to display group of fields in that page dynamically. No need to do code modifications to the page, In field set only you can add, remove & reorder fields

You can refer [this blog](https://www.biswajeetsamal.com/blog/field-set-in-salesforce/) for your requirement.

Comment: I am not developing the page of All Related Records page.  Instead, I just want to use the standard All Related Records page and want to know how to control the fields showed there.